# How to avoid dropping message due to lock timeout in akka actor?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

Bellow is a row from following build log: https://travis-ci.org/plokhotnyuk/actors/jobs/4088637/#L630

```
[WARN] [01/11/2013 12:26:04.908] [Thread-47] [akka://system/user/$t] dropping message of typeclass com.github.plokhotnyuk.actors.Message due to lock timeout
```

Is any ability to configure this timeout or avoid lock at all?

Code of test is here: 
https://github.com/plokhotnyuk/actors/blob/master/src/test/scala/com/github/plokhotnyuk/actors/AkkaActorSpec.scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This timeout is configurable in `akka.actor.unstarted-push-timeout`, but if you are creating many top level actors (`system.actorOf`) you should create the actors a children of another actor instead (`context.actorOf`).